# Why is this question a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicates

[What are all the published objects that require the Use an Object action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/150224/what-are-all-the-published-objects-that-require-the-use-an-object-action?noredirect=1#comment386896_150224)

To me marking this as a duplicate is akin to marking "What are the ingredients and their ratios in Coca Cola?" with duplicate because there has been another question asking "Whats in Coca Cola?" with an answer "Water"

What do you guys think, is this a duplicate and why?

Comment: I understand the eagerness in getting your question open but opening a meta post about it may be a bit premature. The question is still in the reopen review queue (and it already has a few reopen votes). It may just get reopened given enough time.

Comment: There are two questions linked to your question as duplicates. Is your reasoning here intending to refer to one of them or both?

Comment: I would say it is a duplicate of neither, but I made this because a moderator guy told me this was probably my best bet to get my post reopened. However that is besides the point, as I would want you to base your answers on the posts.

Comment: A better tack here, and you can submit your own answer, would be to specify why *you* don't think it's a duplicate. That's the piece that's missing here. If you can explain why it's not, then we can help rewrite the question to reopen it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## It was a duplicate

Your examples prove the point as well. Both questions are asking "What is in coca cola"? The question may have the answer 'water', and so it's asked again.

But asking the same question again because you don't like the current answer doesn't make it not a duplicate.

It's a duplicate because it's the same question - it's just that you want to get a better answer to the question. Putting a bounty on the earlier question is the way to do that.

### Question updated to ask for a list of actionable objects

This is now a defined list question. It's doable, but beware that it may attract downvotes because folks don't always love to be asked to do the heavy lifting work anyone could do themselves.

Comment: In my analogy there the point was that one question asked for the ratio as well as the ingredients, thus making them different.

Comment: @Ragatokk So what makes your actual question different than the ones currently marked as a duplicate?

Comment: Neither of the other questions ask for a full list of the items that work with it.

Comment: Ok, it looks like that's a list question with a definition we can provide. It's a low effort question (downvotable), but answerable. I'll vote to reopen and let someone answer it.

Answer (score 5):

### This question is not a duplicate.

To stick to a similar analogy:

[What does Use an Object cover?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49825/what-does-use-an-object-cover) asks for how you can identify a product and your question asks for a list of all products that can be identified that way. [What items can a Thief use as a bonus action with his Fast Hands?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72270/what-items-can-a-thief-use-as-a-bonus-action-with-his-fast-hands) asks if their list is correctly identified. Neither body asks for a list, even if the header makes it seem that way.

Before your update to the question, your question asked not only for a product list but also how each of the products on the list functions (I would have voted that as too broad), and up to revision 11 how you can identify them (I would assume that this was the source of marking it as a duplicate, which was correct at that time) - after revision 11 not how you can identify them and never if they are correctly identified.

**It was a duplicate until [Revision 11](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/150224/11).**

Comment: I would click accept your answer, but I don't think it is fair until I see how other people vote as I am rather biased here.

Comment: You can find "exhaustive list" in the original question.

Comment: @Ragatokk yes., but you can also find the duplicate source in the source.

Comment: And you phrased that duplicate source as the question and the exhaustive list as an afterthought.

Comment: I see your point, I phrased it wrong. I meant to say I am aware that a similar question has been asked before. Thank you for pointing out my mistake.